# I need a dict in a list

Tags: python, sql, list, dictionary

I am trying to create a list with multiple dicts like this:

`[ { token_id: 7183938r8393}, { token_id: 82838rhf88381}, ... ]`

My code is this:

```
import pyodbc
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import json

def all_token(x): 
con = pyodbc.connect(Trusted_connection='yes', driver= '{SQL Server}',server = 'DESKTOP- 
9S6405A\SQLEXPRESS' ,database ='Q42') 
cursor = con.cursor()
list = []
my_dict = {}
cursor.execute("SELECT [tokens ].token_id FROM [tokens ]")
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    list.append(row)
    print(list)

def listToDict(list):

    convert = { f"Token ID {str(i)}" : list[i][0] for i in range(0, len(list))}
    return convert
    
all_token(list)

print(list)
dict = listToDict(list)

print(dict)
```

and I receive the following error message:

```
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

Comment: Do not use `list`, `dict` or any other name of built-in function/constant as a name of variable.

Answer (score 4):

`list = []`

In this line you have defined a variable called `list`.
This will mess everything up because `list` is a class.

**Do not use keywords as variable names**

Instead, rename the variable to something like `my_list`

Answer (score 2):

> `TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()`

The error here is that `list` is a reserved word and isn't supposed to be used as a variable. Change your variable name and you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Your indentation seems to be broken. Also, you shouldn't name list with a name of a keyword. So I will use `list1`.
You send `list1` to the  `all_token()` which does not make any sense, because you will create `list1` in `all_token` function. So may be you should type:

```
return list1
```

instead of:

```
print(list1)
```

...and then instead of

```
all_token(list1)
```

write...

```
list1 = all_token()
```

Also, you need to remove `x` in arguments to all_token(). Now you have `list1` and can convert it to a dictionary or whatever you want.